# How to choose a color of the palette manually?

Tags: echarts

I have two simple bar charts in two different  elements one beneath the other. I use the default color palette, so the first chart shows the first color. Now i want the second chart to NOT show the first but the third color.

In theory i thought about something like this:

```
series: [{
  data: obj_sumsMonth,
  type: 'bar',
  itemStyle: {
    color: default_palette_color[2]
  }
}]
```

I know that i can define my colors manually, but i would like to prefer to "call" the colors from the palette. Is this possible in echarts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specified colors in option.colors, for instance:

```
option = {
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        boundaryGap: false,
        data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'value'
    },
    series: [{
        data: [820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320],
        type: 'line',
        areaStyle: {}
    }],
    color: "#9ED8F1"
};
```

As for `default_palette_color[2]`, I couldn't make it work in https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=area-basic